# What is the origin of "shh"?

Tags: etymology, exclamations, sounds

The word "sh" (or "shh") is an exclamation for silence:

> Shh! They're listening...

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=sh) only mentions a date (1847) and the common practice of "putting a finger to the lips." Does anyone else have more information about its origin?

Comment: In Italian we say "shhh!" There must be a common root, but I can't find anything :|

Comment: @Alenanno - when I was in the Sistine Chapel, what I heard the security guards keep saying was "sssss" rather than "shhh" - it was an extremely annoying sound!

Comment: @neil Oh yes, there's that variant. And it's annoying as hell! :D

Comment: @neil: It is rather curious that this is used to urge someone to be silent, as the 's' and 'sh' sound is heard over most other spoken sounds. So it makes more sound to tell someone to be quiet than the original offence. In choirs, the singers are often told to dampen 's' sounds, and even not sing them at all (just leave it to one or two people).

Comment: @awe: It would need to be loud to overcome the noise from the person you want to silence. Otherwise, how would they hear it? That being said, de-s'ing vocalists *is* truly a pain I know from experience. Not a trivial task without the proper equipment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Many words which mean "silence, please" have the digraph 'sh'. E.g. **hush** and **shush**.

The origin of all these words however, was the Middle English word *huisst*(pronounced "wheesht"), which originated in round about 1350–1400A.D. *Huisst* as expected, meant "silence, peace".

The Scottish plea for silence also includes the 'sh' digraph: *wheesht*.

The sound for signalling a desire for quiet has long been associated with the sound 'sh'.

Answer (score 5):

It's been a while since I read the book, but Fredrik Lindström's "Jordens smartaste ord" (ISBN: 9789100580360) discusses the word "shh" in depth and posits it's the only word common to all human languages. It's even present in languages that don't use the sound.

Since it's been so long since I read the book, I don't know his sources.

Comment: Hm. I only have _Världens dåligaste språk_, so I can’t check… but it seems rather like an overstated, unchecked factoid to say that ‘shh’ is common to all human languages. I sincerely doubt it is.

Comment: I agree with @JanusBahsJacquet It's a false claim that "it's the only word common to all human languages". In Chinese for instance, you just say the actual word an1jing4 ("silence"). If you said shh, nobody would know what you mean.

Comment: @yong321 That’s not entirely true – I have absolutely heard Chinese people using 嘘 _xū_ to hush others (myself included), and though that’s not quite the same as ‘shh’, it’s pretty close phonetically. When used as an interjection, it’s even quite common to suppress/devoice the vowel, so the verb would be [ɕʷyː˥], whereas the interjection would be [ɕʷː(y̥)].

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet By 嘘, you must be referring to "Pronunciation 2" at https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%99%93#Chinese, where it says "(Mandarin, interjection) hush! shh!" I can tell you if you go to a small town in China and want to tell people to keep quiet and say that, people won't understand you. The meaning of "hush" or "shh" must be a recent borrowing, so in a big city especially in a crowd of people that know enough western culture, that meaning, combined with the context, will be understood. In an English speaking country, even among all Chinese immigrants, yes, sure.

Comment: @yong321 That’s possible; I don’t know. I’ve never lived in the countryside in China, but when I lived in Beijing about 18 years ago, I had a roommate who was a migrant worker, and he definitely used it. I don’t know exactly where he was from, but it was some definitely rural part of Zhejiang – his family lived on farming, and he left school and home at 14 (he was 18 when I knew him) to find better-paying work in the city. I’m relatively sure I first learnt it from him… though it was a while ago, and I might have known it already. I can still hear him say it, though.

Comment: Actually, looking at Wiktionary, I see they list the interjection as _shī_, which is entirely unfamiliar to me. I wouldn’t know what someone meant if they used that either (unless context made it clear, which it often would, of course). I’ve only ever heard _xū_.

Answer (score 4):

An answer for which I do not have a source, but is worth consideration, is that the sound "shhh" is soothing to babies, perhaps because it imitates the sounds in the womb.

Answer (score 3):

Could be related to

> hu**sh**

Which has been around since the 1600s

Answer (score 1):

Taking an educated guess here:

If you want to silence somebody by means of sound, you usually want to make a sound that is audible to a close addressee but not to somebody further away (whom you do not want to hear you).

The latter excludes low-frequency vowels and voiced consonants as they contain low-frequency sounds which are carried well over distance and barriers (there is a reason why you devoice when whispering). It also excludes high-frequency vowels and [plosives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_consonant) (stop consonants) as they stand out against ambient sounds (at least, if you want them to be audible by the addressee). For the same reason, you also want to exclude using more than one sound/phoneme.

When restricting ourselves to the English phoneme repertoire, this leaves us with *fff, hhh, sss, shh* and *thh* (IPA: f, h, s, ʃ, θ). Of these, *hhh* is confusable with abnormal breathing and (in my personal opinion) *fff, sss* and *thh* stand out more against ambient sound than *shh,* which is acustically similar to white noise.

Thus, *shh* seems the most logical sound to use for such a purpose.

Comment: Plosives ‘stand out against’ ambient sounds? How so, exactly? A simple [p] doesn’t really stand out against any ambient sound to my ear—in fact, I’d consider it quite unsuitable to hush someone because it blends in so well that it’s pretty much _inaudible_. Hushing sounds kind of need to be continuants to be very useful.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Well, I guess, it all boils down to what you consider the default intensity of a single [p] (which is pretty much left to opinion as we do not use this in everyday language), but I think we can agree that if the [p] is pronounced loud enough to be audible by the addressee, it would also stand out against ambient sound.